# Loading huge amount of data in Multiple Tabs (3) using jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, jsp

This is my first post at Stackoverflow :)

In my app, I have to load data from mysql using jquery using jQuery. The amount of data is huge. I have 3 tabs and data in each tab is linked with each other based on selection. Below is the screenshot,
[Data loading Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKIWs.png)

In the first tab, got about 5k rows, second got 20k and third got about 50k rows. I wrote the whole thing myself but it takes about 2 to 3 mins to load all the data. Is there a better way to do it? my target to load the whole data within 10 - 20 seconds.

Thanks

Comment: One option would be to load the first page (20 or so) and then load then rest as the user scrolls down (infinite scroll).  Another option would be to page by letter - user is shown letter links, clicks 'A' and it dynamically loads the entries starting with A.   Browsers simply aren't designed to show that amount of data in one go (and it's all-but unusable by users having to scroll 50k rows to find the one they want)

Comment: FYI You might like to remove 'Is there any jQuery plugin...' part as that makes this question off-topic.   Please have a look around the [tour], including https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask